# Processing data in chunks

Tags: r

I have a dataset "X" of about 8 million observations and 5 characters variables - call them A, B, C, D and E. I am trying to calculate the jaro-winkler statistics between D and E with the `RecordLinkage` package:

```
library(RecordLinkage)
X$jw = jarowinkler(X$D, X$E)
```

The problem is that more and memory keeps getting used up till the computer simply freezes. Is there any way of automatically doing the processing in "chunks", without actually having to manually split X into reasonably small sizes beforehand and working with the individual subsets?

In other words, is there any built-in function which does the splitting and processing without me having to do it upfront?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the simplest solution would probably to be to use the `nrows` argument to `read.table` (or CSV or whatever). Set nrows to a small value, and then loop through the segments, removing unwanted objects and calling `gc()` as you go.

Comment: At present, this does indeed appear to be the least painful option.